# Undefined method 'permissions_for' for Permissions:Module in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, module, ruby-on-rails-6

I am returning to Rails after 5 years out of it and trying to understand the changes.  I am going through Ryan Bates' Railscasts looking to update a template I built some years ago and am getting the above error when initializing the `permissions` class for authentication. (See [RC#386](http://railscasts.com/episodes/386-authorization-from-scratch-part-2?autoplay=true) about 18:00 into the playback.)

Rails has changed the `before_filter` to `before_action` (makes sense...) and I have the following in the `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :authorize

  delegate :allow?, to: :current_permission
  helper_method :allow?

  delegate :allow_param?, to: :current_permission
  helper_method :allow_param?

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user

  def current_permission
    @current_permission ||= Permissions.permission_for(current_user)
  end

  def current_resource
    nil
  end

  def authorize
    if current_permission.allow?(params[:controller], params[:action], current_resource)
      current_permission.permit_params! params
    else
      redirect_to root_url, alert: "Not authorized."
    end
  end
end
```

My `permissions.rb` file has the following:

```
module Permissions
  def self.permission_for(user)
    if user.nil?
      GuestPermission.new
    elsif user.admin?
      AdminPermission.new(user)
    else
      MemberPermission.new(user)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting the above error: `NoMethodError at /undefined method "permission_for" for Permissions:Module` from BetterErrors (and Puma).  However the method should be defined in the `Permissions` module; it's right there.  Yet somehow, something has changed in Rails that I can't figure out.

I have tried to `require` the file: nothing.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a module in a class to use it.  It then adds functionality to that class, you do not access methods in module itself.

I'm guessing you need to do something like this (not tested):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Permissions
  
  before_action :authorize
```

change your module to:

```
module Permissions
  def permission_for(user)
  ...
```

and then permissions_for is available in your controller

```
def current_permission
  @current_permission ||= permission_for(current_user)
end
```

The only thing that has changed in Rails is how folders and files are included.  The lib folder inside your rails app is not autoloaded by default.

I think best practice is now to add a lib folder within the app folder and then put all your modules and other classes in there.  They will be included as soon as you restart your server.

Comment: Even with the `include Permissions` in the Application Controller, I still get the same error.  (I also tried removing the `self.` declaration in the Permissions module.)  Something fundamental has changed in Rails (from Rails 4, where I last got this code to work) that I'm not understanding...

Comment: I went back to the original files on GitHub and recreated the application in Rails 6 and, with some minor modifications, it worked right out of the box..  I'm not sure why it didn't when I updated it to Rails 6, but I will investigate and post here when I figure it out...